# Does a “slightly shopworn body” mean one is getting old, or getting fat?

Tags: meaning

I read a sentence:

> He looked at his brown but slightly shopworn body in the mirror.

I wonder if it's saying "his body is getting old" or "his body is getting fat"?

Which understanding is more reasonable?

The sentence is from a [dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/shopworn), under the word *shopworn*, which is defined as:

> **shopworn** (*adj.*) made dirty or imperfect by being displayed or handled in a store:
>   *he brought out some shopworn lettuce*
>
> *figurative*
>   *he appraised his brown but slightly shopworn body in the mirror*

Comment: Shopworn - Worn or faded from being on display in a store. So he is getting OLD will be reasonable when compared with FAT. But he doesn't need to be old at all for his body to fade/look worn, it may have many other reasons.

Comment: As Indiana Jones once famously said, "It's not the years, it's the mileage." *Shopworn* gets across much the same idea: that of being dinged up and faded through use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word *shopworn* is a variant of *worn*, which is defined in the same dictionary as:

> **worn** (*adjective*) damaged and shabby as a result of much use:
>   *a worn, frayed denim jacket*
>
> very tired:
>   *his face looked worn and old*

So I would say that *shopworn* is more related to age than to weight. However, I don't think it's simply old age. I think the phrase "of much use" is important – a man can be 80 and the word *shopworn* might not be a good fit. I'd interpret a *shopworn* body to be one that's perhaps a bit old, but feeling the effects of "much use." Perhaps the subject worked as a laborer for several years, and his joints are achy and stiff. It's not a word that's commonly used, though, so it's hard to say for sure.

Incidentally, I did a Google search for `"a shopworn body"`, and the search engine return [just one hit](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=%22a%20shopworn%20body%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8). That sentence referred to an aging boxer, which seems to confirm my conjecture. Changing the search to `"his shopworn body"` returned just three more, all referring to career wrestlers or boxers. 40 is not necessarily old, but, in those sports, it's plenty old enough for a professional athlete to become *shopworn*.